# Issue with absolute/relative positioning

Tags: html, css

Below is the code I am working on. As you can see, there is a '#parent' div and a '#child' div. the '#child' div has an undefined height, this is because sometimes, the height of the '#child' is smaller or longer than it's parent's height which is '400px' as written below. The problem I am getting is, whenever the child's height is longer than the #parents height, the #child's content's overlaps or pass outside the parent's wrap.

```
<style>
  #parent{
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
  }

  #child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px; 
  }
</style>

<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">
      //Some content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you setting a height on `#parent`?

Comment: What do you *want* to happen when the child is taller than the parent?

Comment: I want to stretch the #parent's height as well if the child is taller than the parent.

Comment: Then you probably don't want absolute positioning on the child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want any overflowing content on `#child` to be hidden, use:

```
#parent {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you still want to be able to see all the content in `#child`, you can contain it in a scrollbar. Then the height of `#child` won't clash with the height of `#parent`.

```
#parent {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want `#parent`'s height to stretch with `#child`, `#child` cannot be absolute positioned. Take that off, and it will work. If you want height to be at least 400px, then you can use:

```
#parent {
   min-height: 400px;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VYrLh/

Comment: It just cut off the excess content, and create a scroll bar. What I want is to kinda stretch the #parent's height depending on the child's height. IF the child's height is longer, I want the parent's to be stretched longer.

Comment: @Ilikebanana Well in that case, why are you making `#child` an absolute positioned element?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
overflow: auto;
```

to the #parent style.

Comment: It just cut off the excess content, and create a scroll bar. What I want is to kinda stretch the #parent's height depending on the child's height. IF the child's height is longer, I want the parent's to be stretched longer.

Answer (score 0):

An absolute positioned element doesn't follow any of it's parent CSS rules.
Just add following in child selector

```
  #child{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    max-height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

Comment: As I stated, the #child have undefined height. Which means, it could either be shorter than 400px or longer than 400px.

Comment: Then I'm sorry to say that you cannot contain child selector (absolute positioned) inside parent selector (relative positioned) and expect parent to grow according to child with pure CSS. Correct me if I'm wrong.